# Nuget Package Manager combining local and external servers

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

Hoping for a little help here. I've a custom built dll which has a dependency on EntityFramework. I've deployed the custom build dll to our local nuget server. However I have not deployed EntityFramework. That is available on the external nugget servers.

When I attempt to install my custom build dll using the Nuget Solution Manager, I get the following error:

Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'CustomBuilt.dll.2016.10.10.6' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Unable to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework.dll'. Source(s) used: 'LocalServer', 'NugetAlt1', 'NugetAltHttps', 'nuget.org', 'Microsoft and .NET'.

The url's for external Servers are:
NugetAlt1: http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/
NugetAltHttps: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
nuget.org: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Microsoft and .Net: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/

I am using VS2015. I've also tried with VS2013.

Also I've added a nuget.config file to the solution. Still getting the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="LocalServer" value="http://localserver:8089/nuget" />
    <add key="NugetAlt1" value="http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/" />
    <add key="NugetAltHttps" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
</configuration>
```

Any thoughts/ideas?

Kind Regards,
Fiona

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it.. The problem was in the nuspec file that I was using to generate the package. The id of my dependencies was incorrect.

I specified the following:

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency id = "EntityFramework.dll" version = "6.0.0.0" />
</dependencies>
```

This is incorrect. The package name of EF is EntityFramework not EntityFramework.dll

This is how it should be specified:

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency id = "EntityFramework" version = "6.0.0.0" />
</dependencies>
```